# How to install gem pg on mac mini m1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, pg, apple-m1

I'm having trouble installing gem pg on my m1 mac mini. Im trying to host onto Heroku and netlify. Wondering if anyone has found a workaround for this. I have tried several solutions on stack overflow but nothing works.

please help, I consider myself a noob with this kinda stuff.

below is the error im getting.

`

```
jonathanbleibdrey@Little-Mac listen_to_the_humans % gem install pg
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/jonathanbleibdrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pg-1.2.3/ext
/Users/jonathanbleibdrey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby -I /Users/jonathanbleibdrey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210323-28582-1dv0k5o.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /opt/homebrew/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/jonathanbleibdrey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --enable-windows-cross
        --disable-windows-cross
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
        --with-pqlib
        --without-pqlib
        --with-libpqlib
        --without-libpqlib
        --with-ms/libpqlib
        --without-ms/libpqlib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/jonathanbleibdrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/pg-1.2.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jonathanbleibdrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pg-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jonathanbleibdrey/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/pg-1.2.3/gem_make.out
```

`

let me know what I can do or resources I can find, or even if we can zoom to fix it wanted to launch it by need of week.

Answer (score 1):

The key to my initial problem getting `pg` gem to install on my m1 was that installing postgresql via brew did not install a library that the pg gem needs to run. This fixed it:

```
brew install libpq
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"
gem install pg
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: I had some dependency's in my homebrew that was out of date. all I had to do is

> homebrew upgrade

I think.